# How do I test PayPal mass payment in PayPal sandbox account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to test mass payment in my paypal sandbox account. As per paypal documentation it describes steps to transfer money to paypal account only. But I want to transfer money to my customer’s bank account. How can I do this?

FYI: PayPal documentation content

How Do Recipients Get Their Money?
 Every recipient receives an email notifying them of the payment. There are three scenarios for recipients.
 Recipients with a PayPal account tied to the email address that contains the payment notification can click a link in the email message, log in to their account, and access their payments.
If the recipients have a PayPal account, but the payment is sent to an email address that is not tied to their account, they are offered an opportunity to log in to their account. Then, when they log in, the money is deposited to their account and the new email address is added to their account automatically.
If the recipients **do not have a PayPal account**, their email message contains a link that directs them to a PayPal sign-up page. The sign-up process automatically confirms their email address. When they complete the sign-up process, the money is available in their new PayPal account.

Thanks In Advance

K.Lakshmi Priya

Answer (score 1):

PayPal MassPay can only transfer funds between PayPal accounts. It does not currently allow you to pay out to a bank account.